# hide keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard

```
I am new to android, and I would like to implement a tab layout and a viewpager infragments,showing a pop up window, such that when I click a button the pop up window could cover the keyboard and I could view the tab layout within. If it's possible, then is there any example I could refer to?

EDIT: Let me rephrase, What I wanted to ask was how can I put the tab layout and view pager in the pop up window.
```

This is the PopupViewHandler class which handles the creation of the popup window

```
public class PopupViewHandler {
    AppCompatActivity mActivity;
    PopupWindow window;
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    View popupView;


    PopupViewHandler(AppCompatActivity mActivity, Context mContext) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }


    public void setupstuff() {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, (ViewGroup) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.main_layout));

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) popupView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


        window = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


    }
}
```

This is the tab_layout xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how I am initiating this class on a button click from the main activity-

```
 handler = new PopupViewHandler(MainActivity.this, getBaseContext());
                handler.setupstuff();
```

But when I run this and click the button I get the following error:

```
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0085 (com.example.himanshu.myemoticons:id/pager) for fragment FragmentTab{3db8038f #0 id=0x7f0c0085}
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1164)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1402)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
02-26 20:23:17.882 11982-11982/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: Welcome. Please try to look if someone has asked the same question before asking again. In this case, I have given you the link to the answer.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the virtual keyboard using the **InputMethodManager**, calling `hideSoftInputFromWindow`, passing in the token of the window containing your view.

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

You will need context to for initiating the `InputMethodManager` and then you can use this code for the view you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I wasn't particularly looking for this. Let me rephrase, What I wanted to ask was how can I put the tab layout and view pager in the pop up window.

Comment: Please edit your question with this comment, so the next viewers will not be confused too.

Comment: @RicardoAlexandre: Please check the code and the error posted above